# C# MVC: Func<Table1, "runtime type"> How do I get a dynamic type?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sql-order-by, expression

Hey, I'm trying to sort a custom data grid of columns based on what the user clicked. The variable "sort" is being passed to the controller but is just a string saying what column is to be sorted.

I need to get the Type of that column to be used in a LambdaExpression... heres the code

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Table1), "x");
MemberExpression memberExp = Expression.Property(param, sort);      
var lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Table1, int>>(memberExp, new ParameterExpression[] { param });

if (bool.Parse(Session["sort"].ToString()))
    sortedKeys = keys.OrderBy(lambdaExp).Skip((currentPage - 1) * _pageSize).Take(_pageSize);
else
    sortedKeys = keys.OrderByDescending(lambdaExp).Skip((currentPage - 1) * _pageSize).Take(_pageSize);
```

As you can see on line #3 where I pass the delegate Func works from for a column that has a Type of int, but that will change dynamically depending on what column was clicked.

How do I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the column type handy, which will be a System.Type.  Let's call it "columnType".  So what you'd want to do is use the non-generic Lambda method:

```
Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Table1), columnType);
Expression.Lambda(funcType, memberExp, new ParameterExpression[] { param });
```